# I've read many books and became an expert in a subject area - would it be a copyright infringement if I share my knowledge on my blog?

Tags: blog, legal, copyright

Let's say I've read many books and became an expert in a subject area. If I share my knowledge on my blog with details and start to earn some money, would I infringe upon the copyright of these book authors?

Comment: Are you planning to copy these books (or excerpts from these books) to your blog, or are you planning to share the knowledge you have learned from these books in your own words?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I won't copy or excerpt but sentences will mean same things (I will also read english books but write in my own language). I already can never understand why sharing some info causes copyright infringement, everybody learns somethings from somebody. These book authors did the same thing too.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister according to which words in copyright.gov, you decided that information itself isn't covered under copyright law? Anyway, currently your last comment is the best answer. I will accept it, if you send it as an answer. You provided good info, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to copyright.gov](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-general.html):

> Copyright protects original works of authorship [...] Ideas and discoveries are not protected by the copyright law, although the way in which they are expressed may be.

So that means that information (ideas) themselves aren't covered under copyright law, just the way that information is expressed (including but not limited to the exact wording). It's the difference between copying something verbatim versus presenting similar ideas in with your own wording and expositional style.

As a rule of thumb, imagine turning in your blog article to your high school teacher as an essay. Would she give you a zero for plagiarism or large swathes of copied content? If so, it's probably copyright infringement.

Also, read up on [the copyright.gov page about fair use](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html), although that might apply more if you were critiquing the original source rather than presenting the ideas from it.

<sub>This answer reflects my interpretation of US law as a layperson, I am not a lawyer nor giving legal advice, and I will not be held liable.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't copy the book's contents but explain it in your own words, it's legal. You can even provide links to the book as proof. In any case, read the copyright notice in the book and notice whether it restricts your use of it.